# xlsx writing - where specified?

Tags: python, xml, xlsx

I'm trying to write a parser in python at the moment, that reads nessus reports and generates xlsx files.

Is there a detailed description of the inner workings of xlsx? I have a hard time trying to find out just by looking at the xml files, where I specify which style is applied to which cell on which sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find full details of the OfficeOpenXML standard on the [ECMA site](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/TC45_available_docs.htm) but why not use one of the existing Python libraries (such as Eric Gazoni's [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/wiki/Home)) to actually generate the xlsx file rather than building your own?

Comment: Thanks, I saw that library too late, and I'm not sure if it can actually do everything I need. But the ECMA site is gold. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure if you used openpyxl as a base, it does a lot of the work for you and could be extended... and I'm sure Eric would appreciate any contributions to the codebase